# How to solve problem with render with boolean modifier?

Tags: rendering, modifiers, boolean-modifier

I just use modifier boolean and it brake my render, idk why.

Link to file https://mega.nz/file/UiN3mIiI#2amb61yz-1j7d43prSwPikVC_aZ4DHoFfJAlVLNaPrk

[image: model in layout]

[image: model in render]

[image: modifiers in invisible part in render]

Comment: Mirror modifiers after booleans before mirror modifiers are usually applying on a non-manifold mesh and that doesn't normally work. Try putting it after.
It's likely not showing in the render because the normals are inverted

Comment: the modifier stack seems weird but please share your file so that we can take a look

Comment: @moonboots add link to my file, check if you can pls

Comment: You generally put the Boolean modifiers before the Subdivision Surface, also only use Boolean if this is necessary because it tends to mess the topology, so maybe try to model your gun without Boolean if you can avoid it

Comment: @moonboots Thank you, i will try to do it without booleans, i just dontn know how to do it by another way. Its just my first time using blender. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you use different subdivision levels for the Render, whatever you see in the Viewport may not match what you see in the Render.

If the problem still persists after equating the subdivision levels, try the *Exact* Solver. Also, try to enable *Self Intersection* and/or *Hole Tolerant* under Solver Options.

[image: Boolean Modifier]

---

**Update:** I downloaded the file, and for each Subdivision modifier on each object, I set the Render Levels (marked red in the screenshot below) to the same value as the Viewport Levels (the number right above it), and that fixed the problem.

[image: Subdivision]

A test render is attached below.

[image: Test]

Comment: Thanks, but i cant solve it by this way, but i click to "Apply"(Ctrl+A) in modifier(subdivision) and part of gun appear. Sorry if i miss smth im newbie

Comment: I updated my answer with screenshots. Please check it out.